# Как отобразить созданный viewController в contentView.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

Доброго времени суток дорогие друзья, заранее извиняюсь за такой вопрос. Я хочу создать viewPager на ios используя библиотеку XlPagerTabStrip (https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip). 
Я взял готовый пример с гитхаба. 
Мой класс InstagramExampleViewController который наследует от ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController:

```swift
import Foundation
import XLPagerTabStrip
class InstagramExampleViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!
    let blueInstagramColor = UIColor(red: 37/255.0, green: 111/255.0, blue: 206/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // change selected bar color
        settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = blueInstagramColor
        settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
        settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
        settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
        settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true
        settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
        settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
        changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
            guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
            oldCell?.label.textColor = .black
            newCell?.label.textColor = self?.blueInstagramColor
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // MARK: - PagerTabStripDataSource
    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        let child_1 = TableChildExampleViewController(style: .plain, itemInfo: "FOLLOWING")
        let child_2 = ChildExampleViewController(itemInfo: "YOU")
        return [child_1, child_2]
    }
    // MARK: - Custom Action
    @IBAction func closeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Класс DataProvider.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataProvider {
    static let sharedInstance = DataProvider()

    lazy var postsData: NSArray = {
        let jsonStr = "[{\"post\":{\"id\":113,\"text\":\"We're getting fifty percent of the t-shirt sales\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-17T00:45:40.556Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Lisa Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Lisa_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":66,\"text\":\"Eep!\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-09T21:29:59.982Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Bart Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Bart_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":42,\"text\":\"I'm not thinking straight, why did I have that wine cooler last month?\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-09T17:58:41.704Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Ned Flanders\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Ned_Flanders.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":84,\"text\":\"Son, when you participate in sporting events, it's not whether you win or lose: it's how drunk you get.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-03T20:21:32.119Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Homer Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Homer_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":75,\"text\":\"I'm normally not a praying man, but if you're up there, please save me Superman.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-03T02:04:43.053Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Homer Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Homer_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":26,\"text\":\"Homer, please get rid of that pig.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-02T03:48:56.381Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Marge Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Marge_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":40,\"text\":\"You sold weapon-grade plutoneum to the Iraqies without a mark up.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-28T05:23:24.657Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Montgomery Burns\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Montgomery_Burns.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":28,\"text\":\"Homer, don't say that. The way I see it, if you raised three children who can knock out and hog tie a perfect stranger you must be doing something right.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-22T14:24:22.408Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Marge Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Marge_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":48,\"text\":\"Hi-dilly-ho, neighborinos!\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-21T08:39:20.764Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Ned Flanders\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Ned_Flanders.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":78,\"text\":\"Maybe, just once, someone will call me 'Sir' without adding, 'You're making a scene.'\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-20T02:44:28.075Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Homer Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Homer_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":33,\"text\":\"This is the type of trickery I pay you for.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-18T08:25:14.507Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Montgomery Burns\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Montgomery_Burns.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":72,\"text\":\"Oh, so they have internet on computers now!\",\"created_at\":\"2014-03-03T19:02:56.032Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Homer Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Homer_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"You know, I do! I mean, there comes a time in a man's life when he asks himself, 'who will float my corpse down the Ganges?'\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-24T14:09:00.912Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Apu Nahasapeemapetilon\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":62,\"text\":\"Ay Caramba!\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-18T16:38:37.958Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Bart Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Bart_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":19,\"text\":\"Throughout the ages, the finger painter, the Play-Doh sculptor, the Lincoln Logger, stood alone against the daycare teacher of her time. She did not live to earn aproval stickers, she lived for herself, that she might achieve things that are the glory of all humanity. These are my terms. I do not care to play by any others. And now, if the jury will allow me, it's naptime.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-16T22:11:33.236Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Maggie Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Maggie_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":76,\"text\":\"Son, if you really want something in this life, you have to work for it. Now quiet! They're about to announce the lottery numbers.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-16T19:09:55.062Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Homer Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Homer_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":22,\"text\":\"Somebody throw the goddamn bomb!\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-16T13:50:25.313Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Marge Simpsons\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Marge_Simpsons.png\"}}},{\"post\":{\"id\":36,\"text\":\"Oh, so mother nature needs a favor? Well, maybe she should have thought of that when she was besetting us with droughts and floods and poison monkeys.\",\"created_at\":\"2014-02-13T06:51:57.549Z\",\"user\":{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Montgomery Burns\",\"imageURL\":\"http://obscure-refuge-3149.herokuapp.com/images/Montgomery_Burns.png\"}}}]"
        let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let res = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) // swiftlint:disable:this force_try
        return res as! NSArray // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
    }()
}

class NavController: UINavigationController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}
```

Класс PostCell

```swift
import UIKit

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postText: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

    func configureWithData(_ data: NSDictionary) {
        if let post = data["post"] as? NSDictionary, let user = post["user"] as? NSDictionary {
            postName.text = user["name"] as? String
            postText.text = post["text"] as? String
            userImage.image = UIImage(named: postName.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_"))
        }
    }

    func changeStylToBlack() {
        userImage?.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        postText.text = nil
        postName.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size:18) ?? .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        postName.textColor = .white
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255.0, green: 16/255.0, blue: 16/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Класс TableChildExampleViewController:

```swift
import Foundation
import XLPagerTabStrip

class TableChildExampleViewController: UITableViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

    let cellIdentifier = "postCell"
    var blackTheme = false
    var itemInfo = IndicatorInfo(title: "View")

    init(style: UITableView.Style, itemInfo: IndicatorInfo) {
        self.itemInfo = itemInfo
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PostCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        if blackTheme {
            tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255.0, green: 16/255.0, blue: 16/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataProvider.sharedInstance.postsData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PostCell,
            let data = DataProvider.sharedInstance.postsData.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary else { return PostCell() }

        cell.configureWithData(data)
        if blackTheme {
            cell.changeStylToBlack()
        }
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider
    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }

}
```

и класс ChildExampleViewController:

```swift
import Foundation
import XLPagerTabStrip

class ChildExampleViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

    var itemInfo: IndicatorInfo = "View"

    init(itemInfo: IndicatorInfo) {
        self.itemInfo = itemInfo
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "XLPagerTabStrip"

        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -50))
    }

    // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider
    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }
}
```

Я только недавно начал изучать swift(UI).
Как мне теперь все это отобразить в contentView.swift ?? Заранее Благодарю!!

Comment: если вы хотите переписать все это на SwiftUI, то разбейте вашу задачу на подзадачи и начните реализацию самостоятельно поэтапно - например: как сделать листание, как сделать вывод данных в таблицу и тд, на данный момент ваш вопрос слишком обширен

Comment: понятно,  посмотрите пожалуйста на мой следующий вопрос, благодарю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078961/xlpagertabstrip-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-buttonbar